# Images within JButton not displayed

Tags: java, swing, package, imageicon

Can someone please have a look at this code and tell me what am I doing wrong?  The images are not being displayed at all.  They are in the same package.

Thanks

```
    public class MWindow31Pic extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
       private JPanel contPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
       private JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("open.jpg"));
       boolean clicked = false;

    public MWindow31Pic(String title){
      super(title);
      this.build();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       if (! clicked) {
          button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("close.jpg"));
          //button.setText("You clicked ME!!!!"); 
          clicked = true;
       }
       else{
          button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("open.jpg"));
          //button.setText("Click Me"); 
          clicked = false;
       }
    }

    public void build(){
        // adding JComponents
        contPane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

       // JFrame settings    
       this.setResizable(false);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setSize(240,188);
       this.setVisible(true);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create ImageIcon like this:

```
new ImageIcon ( MWindow31Pic.class.getResource ( "close.jpg" ) )
```

Because with your way:

```
new ImageIcon ( "close.jpg" )
```

image should be inside the application working directory but not inside the calling class package.

You might also want to move images into a separate folder:

```
new ImageIcon ( MWindow31Pic.class.getResource ( "images/close.jpg" ) )
```

Comment: It gets the local URL of image file that is contained inside your jar (or outside in case classes aren't packed yet). Just try to output that URL as string and see what it gives to you, for example like this: System.out.println ( MWindow31Pic.class.getResource ( "close.jpg" ) );